# Safari Webpage Development Hardware: Mac [mini], iPad, iPhone or iTouch

Tags: web-development, apple

The company I work for is finding that a majority of our users use iPhone's with our web services.  Since I only have Android and Windows devices, I cannot test Safari myself and therefore occasionally run into Safari-only issues.  As a result, I'm looking into getting my first Apple device for testing Safari (as opposed to using a paid testing service).

My thoughts:

- iTouch seams like a great, cheap alternative but the screensize is considerably smaller then the iPhones I'm targeting.
- iPhone would work as it is the best way to see what clients see but is a waist of a phone just for Safari and can be quite expensive for something more current.
- iPad gives you more space to work with but not sure if I can scale down the browser to simulate an iPhone's size (again, Apple newbie here!).
- Base Mac Mini, compared to iPads and iPhones, isn't much more and allows me to test Safari at many sizes as well as run simulator's with [free] xCode.  Not to mention lets me start learning the macOS ecosystem and start with mac/iOS development.  No touch capabilities and Safari implementation not exactly the same as iOS (from what I've read anyway).

Any recommendations on devices, new or used, from Apple users would be great! (I would like to get a number of years out of it so I would rather it not be terribly outdated.)

Comment: Get the company to buy iPads. Scaling issues? Use Bootstrap or something. Shouldn't need multiple different screen sizes to test a web page then.

Comment: Already responsive (Angular Material with flex layout). End users are very particular about maximizing the use of their display.